# Why are these elements appearing behind each other/mixing

Tags: html, css

I was creating a web portfolio, I created the welcome section then I created the projects section, but the projects section appears behind the welcome section. Why is this happening? I tried making some elements as block but it won’t work.

```css
*{  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;            
}
body{
    background-color: black;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1% 0.8%;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #888888;
}
.logo{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Staatliches';
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: larger;
}
.nav-area{
    list-style: none;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.nav-area li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-area li a{
    transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    color: white;
}
.nav-area li a:hover{
    color: rgb(0, 204, 255);
}

.text-container{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 13%;
    top: 42%;
    transform:translate(-13%, -42%);
}
.text-container p:nth-child(1){
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 35px;
}
.text-container p:nth-child(2){
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 70px;
}
.text-container p:nth-child(3){
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.model {
    height: 650px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13%;
    left: 70%;
    transform: translateX(-70%);
}
.text-container button{
    width: 130px;
    height: 42px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    outline: none;
    margin: 20px 10px;
}
.hire-btn{
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
.hire-btn{
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
button:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.welcome-section{
    display: block;
}
.projects-section{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10rem 10rem;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rajdeep Thakare</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> </head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo"><h1>Rajdeep Thakare</h1></div>
        <nav>
<ul class="nav-area">
<li><a href="#">home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
    <section class="welcome-section">
<div class="text-container">
    <p>Hello,</p>
    <p>I am Rajdeep</p>
    <p>Maker and Hobbyist!!</p>
    <button class="hire-btn">Hire Me</button>
    <button class="down-btn">Download CV</button>
</div>
    <img class="model" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/12vEKYhBZvpfRXV0aJ1wXmXk59lwplRe0/view?usp=sharing" alt="my photo">
</section>

<section class="projects-section">
    <div>
        <h1>MY PROJECTS</h1>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Code link - https://codepen.io/Rajdeep100/pen/WNQqoGQ?editors=1100

Comment: Note that the error message when you tried to post just the link **did not** tell you to format the link as code, it told you to **include the code**. Please give a [mre].

Comment: `welcome-section` has no height, and its childs are `postion: absolute`, wich means the projects section has space to sit above it. give the `welcome-section` some height and it will work

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am new here, I need to play with all this stuff, thank you for editing

Comment: @Ramon Adding height worked, but when I tried to assign height in %, didn't worked, why wasn't that worked. Thanks!!

Comment: the `element` around the `section` should have a set `height` for a % in `height` to work, because 50% of nothing is still nothing, but 50% of 500px is 250px :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to give some height to your `welcome-section`. Like an example give it 400px to the `welcome-section` class. Check the image given here
[Portfolio Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYocO.png)